# tweepy (Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized)

Tags: python, tweepy, scrape

I want to scrape tweets using API of free developer account. I do not have too much knowledge of using API for scraping.

The code that I am using for scraping is:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key='aaa',
    consumer_secret= 'aaa',
    access_token='bbb',
    access_token_secret='bbb'

)
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key= consumer_key,consumer_secret= consumer_secret,access_token= access_token,access_token_secret= access_token_secret)
query = 'news'
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

## **Error**

```
Unauthorized                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-cdd309f625b4> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key= consumer_key,consumer_secret= consumer_secret,access_token= access_token,access_token_secret= access_token_secret)
     11 query = 'news'
---> 12 tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)
     13 for tweet in tweets.data:
     14     print(tweet.text)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tweepy/client.py in request(self, method, route, params, json, user_auth)
     96                 raise BadRequest(response)
     97             if response.status_code == 401:
---> 98                 raise Unauthorized(response)
     99             if response.status_code == 403:
    100                 raise Forbidden(response)

Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
Unauthorized
```

I tried to update the status of my API using the below code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status("Hello Tweepy")
```

After using the above code for updating status I again run the tweet search code for scrapping but when I run the code than I get an error message. I do not know why this is happening. My developer app has read and write permissions generated keys.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to remove this error and scrape the tweets?

Comment: Looks to me like you are using Twitter API OAuth 1.0a (no bearer token), and I think in this case you have to set `user_auth=True` in the `client.search_recent_tweets` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot scrape tweets ( **Search Tweets** ) using the **Free Level Access** on the Twitter API.

You can use the **Manage Tweets** and **User Lookup** features on **Free Level Access**.

For the **Search Tweets** feature, you have to upgrade to the **Basic Level**.

The syntax to call the **Twitter API v2** is:

```
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)

# Post Tweet
message = "Hello Twitter"
client.create_tweet(text=message)

# Search Recent Tweets (This requires Basic Level Access)
query = 'QUERY'
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

In the second code snippet, you are trying to call the **Twitter API v1.1**, which can only be used for **Media Uploads**.

The correct syntax to call the **Twitter API v1.1** for **Media Upload** is:

```
# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)

# Create API object
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Upload Image
media = api.media_upload("tweet_img.png")
```

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.14.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets

I hope this helps.